# getting error saying unexpected end of file in shell

Tags: shell

I just started working on shell. A small script but ran into issues. I am getting error while executing saying `unexpected end of file in shell`.

Below is the code

#!/bin/bash
    while [ $1 != "" ] ; do
        echo $1
        shift
    don

Note: Edit copying the correct code

```
#!/bin/sh -xv
while [ "$1" != "" ]
do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

giving error as `syntax error near unexpected token`done'`

Comment: I don't see any errors, and running it on my machine works as well. Are you sure that this is exactly what you have in your script?

Comment: yes. May be I am running this on windows machine on cygwin? Are you running this in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash while [ $1 != "" ] ; do echo $1 shift done
```

e was missing in done and also $1 needs to be in quote.

Comment: hey. It was copy mistake. I am pasting the code again

Comment: U running this on linux?

Comment: Ok if you are running on cygwin, there are few things to check 1) Make sure bash is installed or you can give bash home path while running shell scripts 2) YOu need to save your files in UNIX/OSX format ( Notepad ++ has it) 3) before running run dos2unix command

Comment: @ Nitesh : Did it go away?

Comment: It worked.  I converted the file in UNIX/OSX format in notepad++. It worked. Thanks a lot. I tried executing command dos2unix bu cygwin is saying command does not exist